# MySQL - Efficient way to select all attributes that co-occur with list of attributes in many-to-many

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

given the following tables:

```
Thing
  idThing
Attribute
  idAttribute
ThingHasAttribute
  idThing
  idAttribute
```

I would like to select all attributes that co-occur with a list of given attributes.

What I mean by co-occur is the following:

```
Assume there are 2 Things in table Thing:
Thing 1 has Attributes 1, 2, 5
Thing 2 has Attributes 1, 2, 8, 9
Given the Attribute 1, the co-occuring attributes are 2, 5, 8, 9
Given the Attributes 1, 2, the co-occuring attributes are 5, 8, 9
Given the Attributes 1, 2, 8, the co-occuring attribute is 9
```

I managed to trial-and-error a solution but it seems to me that there must be something simpler. Do any of you know of a simpler or more importantly faster way to select those?

What I found is:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag1.idAttribute SEPARATOR ',') FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT Thing.idThing FROM Thing 
 JOIN ThingHasAttribute ta1 ON Thing.idThing=ta1.idThing AND ta1.idAttribute = 1
 JOIN ThingHasAttribute ta2 ON Thing.idThing=ta2.idThing AND ta2.idAttribute = 2
 ...
 ) thingWithAttrs
JOIN ThingHasAttribute tag1 ON thingWithAttrs.idThing = tag1.idThing
WHERE tag1.idAttribute NOT IN ('1', '2', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you mean by "co-occur", you should try using an `INNER JOIN` with the associative table, which will give you records that are in both/all tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM ThingHasAttribute THA
    INNER JOIN Thing T
        ON T.idThing = THA.idThing
    INNER JOIN Attribute A
        ON A.idAttribute = THA.idAttribute
```

Comment: This is not what I meant by co-occuring. But thank you for your answer. It made me realize that I need to add an explanation to my question.